# See MySQL db traffic via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am just wondering if there is a way to see the current bandwidth usage of a MySQL database using php?

For example at the moment I see that mine is using 7mbps with 4 connections etc. via MySQL workbench, I want to be able to print this data using PHP.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, the most you can get is, if you're using the native driver and then making use of the [statistics it has to offer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.stats.php). From what I know all the other mysql drivers don't have something comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `MySQL workbench` is doing.  I wonder if it is just periodically running and graphing the output of this.

```
select BYTES_RECEIVED, BYTES_SENT from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS;
```

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html

> Bytes_received
>
> - The number of bytes received from all clients.
>
> Bytes_sent
>
> - The number of bytes sent to all clients.

Also see the [Show Status page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html).

Comment: `<?php 
include ('../../MySQL.php');
mysql_select_db('information_schema');
$query = mysql_query('select BYTES_RECEIVED, BYTES_SENT from GLOBAL_STATUS');
echo mysql_num_rows($query);` 
I tried that, and it returns invalid?

Comment: `Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result` That is returned because the query returned 0 rows I think

Comment: Hard to tell given your lack of error checking.  What happens if you do a simple `var_dump($query)`?

Comment: Since you have Mysql workbench, what do you see if you run the same query using the client?

Comment: Are you root on the mysql server?  Are you running a recent version?

Comment: No I'm not root but the user I'm using can see the stats in MySQL workbench using MySQL version 5.0.92-community